# System.Security.Policy.Evidence.AddHostEvidence: type argument 'System.Security.Policy.Zone' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, rdlc

I am trying to create rdlc report in blazor server project with .NET6, followed [this blog guide](http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects) which was layed out perfectly but rendering the report I was stuck with this error.

> System.Security.Policy.Evidence.AddHostEvidence: type argument 'System.Security.Policy.Zone' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.'

this error occur when executing `LocalReport report = new LocalReport(pathToRdlc);`

i have search but nothing that helps. the error was [reported on github](https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/issues/27) some days back but no solution yet.

here is a sample project on [github](https://github.com/tharindubuddhi/netcorerdlc/tree/master/ReportAPI) using same guide above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this nuget package `Microsoft.ReportViewer.NETCore` and the [Github repository](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore) as my alternative solution. its almost same implementation as detailed [in this blog here](http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects)
but the get method implementation is as below for the nuget package. it save me from the error above, hope it helps you also.

```cs
 
 string reportName="TestReport"; 
 string reportPath =Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath,"ReportFiles", "SampleReport.rdlc"); //or webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath if your report is in wwwroot folder

 Stream reportDefinition; // your RDLC from file or resource
 //IEnumerable dataSource; // your datasource for the report
 using var fs = new FileStream(reportPath, FileMode.Open);
 reportDefinition = fs;
 LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
 report.LoadReportDefinition(reportDefinition);
 report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("source", dataSource));
 report.SetParameters(new[] { new ReportParameter("parameter1", "RDLC Sample Report ") });
 byte[] pdf = report.Render("PDF");
 fs.Dispose();

 return File(pdf, "application/pdf", reportName + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is the only one that has worked for me for Blazor (net 6). Also reusing the same code!

Answer (score 3):

***System.Security.Permissions***

NuGet\Install-Package System.Security.Permissions -Version 7.0.0

I solved the problem to add the above Nuget Package.
Perfect Working. No error now.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33490893)

Comment: It works for me, seems that a indirect dependency with security permissions 4.7.0 needed to be upated with blazor/net 6.0.

If you used AspNetCore.Reporting in a dependent assembly, Security.Permissions must be installed in the main application project and this solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me installing the package 'System.Security.Permissions' solves the issue.

Comment: this solved my problem in windows, but when deploying in ubunto I get the following error:  System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Access Control List (ACL) APIs are part of resource management on Windows and are not supported on this platform. at System.Security.Policy.Evidence..ctor()
         at AspNetCore.Reporting.ControlService.get_InternetZoneEvidence()
         at AspNetCore.Reporting.ControlService..ctor(ILocalCatalog catalog)
         at AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport..ctor()
         at AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalReport..ctor(String reportPath)

Answer (score 2):

```
dotnet add package System.Security.Permissions --version 7.0.0
```

resolve

Answer (score -1):

I was also using the package AspNetCore.Reporting and having same problems after updating my solution to .net 6.
I changed to ReportViewer.NETCore and that fixed the problem.